# Not getting expected data from SQL Server in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, flask, sqlalchemy

I've been following a course, and I want to change my data source from sqlite to mssql.

I've made the connection, and i'm trying to list the users in my db.
But when I do I get the result show below:
<Users 2>
<Users 3>
Instead of showing the actual user data.

Ive uploaded the code to git:
https://github.com/Desc83/flask_mssql

[image: And it shows like this instead of showing the actual data?]

```
import urllib


import os
import pyodbc 
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect
from flask import Flask
from flask import current_app




app = Flask(__name__)


app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "mssql://@Localhost/FlaskMSSQL?driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False



db = SQLAlchemy(app)

Migrate(app,db)
db.init_app(app)


class Users(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key= True)
    Username = db.Column(db.Text)
    Password = db.Column(db.Text)
    Email = db.Column(db.Text)

def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
  


@app.route('/users')
def listUsers():
    users = Users.query.all()
    test = Users.
    return render_template('listuers.html', users=users)
    
  
  
  
  
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html')




if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

view:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="jumbotron">
  
  <p>list users</p>
  <ul>
    
    {% for user in users  %}
    <li>{{user}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    
    {% for item in user %}
    <li>{{item}}</li>
    
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I have tried to split the data into bits, but it comes with the same result:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="jumbotron">
  
  <p>list users</p>
  <ul>
    
    {% for user in users  %}
    <li>{{user}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    
    {% for item in user %}
    <li>{{item}}</li>
    
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as if you need to specify the `__str__` for the Users class.

Alternatively, you can explicitly indicate the fields you want to display in the template.

Instead of this:

```
{% for user in users  %}
<li>{{user}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Try this:

```
{% for user in users  %}
<li>{{user.Username}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you're showing the entire user object but what you want is just a part of that object. (nice documentation supporting your question, BTW)

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you. It seems to work.

I tried adding

def __repr__(self):
    return f"User: ('{self.username}', '{self.email}')"

def __str__(self):
    return f"User: ('number {id} is: {self.username}', '{self.email}')"


But with same result?